Modifying Bootstrap 5 model content, closing and reopening
I have a modal using the Bootstrap 5 framework.
I post a form that is contained within it to a JQuery ajax call and then modify the modal content based on the result from the JQuery AJax call, then allow the user to close it.
I update the content using three divs in the modal - "error", "content" and "success". JQuery .hide() and .show() depending on the results of the JQuery Ajax Post.
The purpose it to update some account settings and the AJax post is to update the DB.
If they want to then modify the setting again, when they click the "setting", the modal still contains the "success" or "error" result rather than the original modal contents (or updated settings they chose). Perhaps, a better method is to have one "standard" modal and when clicking the setting to a Ajax to get the initial content for the modal, load that into the modal.
It looks like I can fire some BS5 events to put the modal back to it's default state, however, I'm curious if this is the best method to do this or if there is a better method, or whether my other idea would be better.
Below is the update that doesn't fire.


$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#Notifications').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    debugger;
    $(this).find('#error, #success').hide();
    $(this).find('#content').show();
    $(this).find('form')[0].reset();
  });
});
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="modal fade" id="Notifications" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="NotificationsLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="NotificationsLabel">Email Notifications</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="error"></div>
        
        <div id="notificationsBox">
          <table id="content">
            <tr>
              <td><input id="content_notificationFrequency_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$content$notificationFrequency$0" value="1" /><label for="content_notificationFrequency_0">1 day</label></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
              <td><input id="content_notificationFrequency_1" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$content$notificationFrequency$1" value="3" /><label for="content_notificationFrequency_1">3 days</label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
          </table>
          
          <input type="submit" name="ctl00$content$btnSubmit" value="Update" id="content_btnSubmit" class="notifications main-btn" />
        </div>
        
        <div id="success"></div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>




It will be resolved by Reset the model when you click on the close button:
$('#yourModalID').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).find('#error, #success').hide(); 
    $(this).find('#content').show(); 
    $(this).find('form')[0].reset();
});

#yourModalID = Add your model id

Thanks. It's not firing. I've updated by original post with the basic code.

if it is not working, could you please try re-initializing the JQuery Ajax method?
